# Can an end-user use CSS to tell Chrome how to render a website?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scroll

Noob question
(Original problem is below)
I sort-of know how CSS works, but does it have to be part of the html page itself, written by the website creator? I thought that it was possible to use CSS to tell a browser to act a certain way, but I can't find any information on where to put a CSS file if so.

I use macOS Monterey 12.4, and I have to use Chrome for one important website. Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64). But the width of the scroll bar on the right-hand side has suddenly become too narrow, and I can't find any settings to change it. I tried unticking (unchecking) the Scrolling option in Accessibility - Pointer Control, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: You mentioned about browser's dimension, it's client-side settings. You can use JS and CSS to make a custom scrollbar, though. CSS is part of the website, while you can temporarily change the CSS using Developer Console in the browser to modify the CSS on-the-fly, but it's not permanent, as you cannot overwrite the CSS in the website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/52967/change-default-css-of-google-chrome